# I can't access to $ with jquery

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to use a feature of bootstrap 4.6 for modal to pass data in a modal form (using the data-wathever attribute). So I used the code given by bootstrap documentation but it looks like I can't use $ selector from bootstrap.

**I used this line given by bootstrap documentation to import the needed javascript:**

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous" defer></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-9/reFTGAW83EW2RDu2S0VKaIzap3H66lZH81PoYlFhbGU+6BZp6G7niu735Sk7lN" crossorigin="anonymous" defer></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-+YQ4JLhjyBLPDQt//I+STsc9iw4uQqACwlvpslubQzn4u2UU2UFM80nGisd026JF" crossorigin="anonymous" defer></script>
```

**Here is the html code:**

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal" data-whatever="@mdo">Open modal for @mdo</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal" data-whatever="@fat">Open modal for @fat</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal" data-whatever="@getbootstrap">Open modal for @getbootstrap</button>

<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">New message</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <form>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="recipient-name" class="col-form-label">Recipient:</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="recipient-name">
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="message-text" class="col-form-label">Message:</label>
            <textarea class="form-control" id="message-text"></textarea>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Send message</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**And here the js:**

```
$('#exampleModal').on('show.bs.modal', function (event) {
  var button = $(event.relatedTarget)
  var recipient = button.data('whatever') 
  var modal = $(this)
  modal.find('.modal-title').text('New message to ' + recipient)
  modal.find('.modal-body input').val(recipient)
})
```

In the web browser console I get this message of error:
Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined

Do someone know how to fix that ?

**=====EDIT====**

Ok problem is fixed, I will try to explain what happend.

First I moved the script import at the end of the body (so after the block body in twig) and removed the defer attribute.

But, the place where I wanted to use the modal script was in another twig file, and the script was called at the end of block body so the script for modal was called before jquery ... So in base.html.twig, I moved the block javascripts at the end of body and in modal.html.twig I added a block javascripts after the block body with the script in and now it's working fine.

**Here the code of base.html.twig:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <!-- all the head -->
    </head>
    <body>
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">
            <!-- all the navbar -->
        </nav>
        {% block body %}{% endblock %}
    </div>
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/4c50062767.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-9/reFTGAW83EW2RDu2S0VKaIzap3H66lZH81PoYlFhbGU+6BZp6G7niu735Sk7lN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-+YQ4JLhjyBLPDQt//I+STsc9iw4uQqACwlvpslubQzn4u2UU2UFM80nGisd026JF" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    
    {% block javascripts %}
       
    {% endblock %}
  </body>
</html>
```

**And here the code in modal.html.twig:**

```
{% extends 'base.html.twig' %}

{% block body %}
    <!-- all the code of modal -->        
{% endblock %}

{% block javascripts %}
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $('#exampleModal').on('show.bs.modal', function (event) {
            let button = $(event.relatedTarget)
            let recipient = button.data('whatever')
            let modal = $(this)
            modal.find('.modal-body input').val(recipient)
        });
    </script>
{% endblock %}
```

And now it's working fine. Thank you for your help !

Comment: Simple you wrong to the script link, use: [this](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.6/getting-started/introduction/)

Comment: @jeff Are you using Wordpress? If so you'll need to alias `$` using document.ready: `jQuery($ => { /* your code here */ });`

Comment: No he add defer, that block the jquery, try your own without defer

Comment: You're right - my bad. It would be worth explaining that in your original comment as it's easy to miss.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I'm using symfony, I used the defer because I also use twig, and I add javascript in the javascript block which is above the body.

Comment: @SimoneRossaini I put the script at the end of the body part and removed the defer, but it still not working.

Comment: You put jquery and bootstrap release before script?

Comment: @SimoneRossaini Ok I get it now, so I will do an edit to explain what happened but yes it was because the script was called before jquery.